# Question about postgres commits to table in UNLOGGED mode

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables: `data`, `processed`, and `processing_status`. The first one has rows coming in quite quickly. Every few minutes, I check the highest ID in data and compare it to `processing_status`. If enough new datapoints have come in, the new ones are processed and aggregated into `processed` table, and `processing_status` is updated to the highest ID. Obviously, both of those happen in one transaction, so that if there's a crash, everything stays sane, and neither table is updated without the other.

I'd like to improve the performance of this, regarding the bloat to the WAL logs. If I set `processed` and `processing_status` to UNLOGGED in Postgres, will I retain the property that when I commit the transaction, either both tables are updated, or neither? Even in the event of a crash?

I believe that if I set UNLOGGED, the difference is that in a crash, it will always revert both, whereas in LOGGED mode, the WAL could be used to include a few extra in-progress transactions right during the crash. Is this understanding accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. UNLOGGED tables participate in transactions just like regular, logged tables.

The only difference is the crash-safety, so you may lose data if your server crashes (unexpected power-outage, operating system crash, Postgres bug, ...)

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. So postgres is able to guarantee an "either both tables, or neither table gets updated" transaction, but without a WAL log? Amazing. Turning this on right away!

Comment: Just curious: what would happen if I had one LOGGED table and one UNLOGGED table. I update both and commit, then there's a crash. Would I still get an "both, or neither" transaction? If so, how does that possibly work?

Comment: You would be left with a corrupted database in that case.

Comment: Corrupt in the sense that only one would get updated? Or like really corrupted and unusable?

Comment: Corrupted in the sense that the data isn't valid anymore because the contents of the tables don't match what it should be (or is expected), e.g. invalid foreign key values.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that if I set UNLOGGED, the difference is that in a crash, it will always revert both,

No, after a crash the unlogged tables will be truncated.  That is, they will have no rows in them.  You would have to recompute `processed` and `processing_status` in their entirely from `data`, which may or may not be feasible.

> whereas in LOGGED mode, the WAL could be used to include a few extra in-progress transactions right during the crash. Is this understanding accurate?

This would be true only if the commit of the transaction was in-progress, or if a single-statement transaction was occuring in auto-commit mode.  If the body but not the commit of the transaction was in-progress, it will always be rolled back after a crash.

Comment: Are they always truncated after a crash? Or, only when there was a transaction in progress?

Comment: @lurfjurv Always truncated.  It would be nice if you could protect the table by marking them read only, but alas that doesn't work.